# Powershell How To Input Computername To Check

Tags: powershell, service, dns, hostname

I want to check the services for a computer in Powershell. I've made the 'check services' part of the script. I cannot add the additional part to input which server in the domain to check. My script only checks my local computer. I need to be prompted to input which server to check in the LAN.

bot$Servicename = "Security Center"

```
$ServiceName = "Security Center"
function FuncCheckService{
param($ServiceName)}
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
if ($arrService.Status -ne "Running"){
Start-Service $ServiceName
Write-Host "Starting " $ServiceName " service" }
FuncCheckService -ServiceName "security center"
```

Comment: You want to use `Get-Service`, but its remote functionality as [outlined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service).  Look at `-ComputerName` on that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server name'
Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -computername $Server
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the solution I was looking for.